# Issue with delete query for a specific field only

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to delete a specific field **(not an entire row)** in my database. 
But right now, it's not deleting anything in my database.

When the user clicks on the **delete button**, i want to **empty the field** holding the path to the image.

HTML part:

```
<div class="delete_image"><a href="#" id="<?php echo $recipe_path ?>"   
class="delete_image">Remove!</a></div>
```

AJAX Part:

```
$('.delete_image').on("click",function() 
{
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = '$recipe_path='+ ID;
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this image ?"))
  {
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "remove.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,  
   });
}
return false;
});
```

PHP part (remove.php):

```
<?php
include "includes/db.php";

if ($_POST['recipe_path'])
  {
   $recipe_path = $_POST['recipe_path'];
   $sql = query("DELETE FROM recipes WHERE $recipe_path = '$recipe_path' ");
  }
?>
```

Am i doing something wrong with the SQL query ?

Comment: don't use DELETE, you want to use UPDATE and set it to an empty string. DELETE can only delete a whole row

Comment: DELETE will remove an entire row. You say you don't want that, so you should probably look at using UPDATE instead, and setting the correct field to `''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataString does not have the right serialization syntax, that's why the code wasn't working, try changing it to this:

```
var dataString = 'recipe_path='+ ID;
```

Now for the UPDATE code, assuming `ID` above referes to the recipe path, you would need to do something like this:

```
$sql = query("UPDATE recipes SET recipe_path = NULL WHERE recipe_path = '$recipe_path'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldnt that be

```
$sql = query("DELETE FROM recipes WHERE recipe_path = '$recipe_path' ");
```

Why the `$recipe_path`?

Also make sure that you are running the function once the page is ready.

```
$(function(){
     $('.delete_image').on("click",function() 
    {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var dataString = '$recipe_path='+ ID;
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this image ?"))
      {
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "remove.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,  
       });
    }
    return false;
    });
});
```

As has been pointed out, DELETE will delete the whole row.

Comment: @Dagon true, thanks for that. Was helping him on the rest of it, didnt to notice that!